# Copy text from cell from workbook A to cell on workbook B if text condition x

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to copy text from a cell in a worksheet in workbook A, to a cell in a worksheet in workbook B. but... only if the text matches "Whitney EV2" from a different worksheet in workbook A.
I can get the text to copy from A to workbook B but can't get the text condition to match.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This is a bad question. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

So in this example, I am assuming "Whitney EV2" is in workbookA (Sheet1) and you are trying to copy it to workbookB if a cell in workbookA = "Whitney EV2".

You would need to use an *if* statement along with a reference to the workbook.

The code you're looking for in workbookB is

```
=IF('C:\FILEPATH\[workbookA.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1="Whitney EV2","Whitney EV2","")
```

Which means, if cell A1 of Sheet1 of workbookA = "Whitney EV2", output "Whitney EV2" to the cell in workbookB. Otherwise leave it blank.